# Changing from .live to .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I know `.live` was depreciated and recently I was updating a page and realized I was using `.live` I would like to switch to `.on` but do not understand what to change. Here is my current code:

```
    //Script for Choosing which form to display
$("#email-button, #text-button").live('click',
function(){  

    //figure out what button was clicked. 
    if(this.id === "email-button"){
        var btnA = $(this);
        var btnB = $("#text-button");
        var divA = $('#email-form');
        var divB = $('#text-form');
    }
    else{
        btnA = $(this);
        btnB = $("#email-button");
        divA = $('#text-form');
        divB = $('#email-form');
    }

    //make sure it is not already active, no use to show/hide when it is already set
    if(btnA.hasClass('dark_button_span')){
        return; 
    }

    //see if div is visible, if so hide, than show first div
    if(divB.is(":visible")){        
        divB.fadeOut("slow", function(){
             divA.fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }
    else{//if already hidden, just show the first div
        divA.fadeIn("slow");            
    }

    //Add and remove classes to the buttons to switch state
    btnA.addClass('dark_button_span').removeClass('light_button_span');
    btnB.removeClass('dark_button_span').addClass('light_button_span');
  }    
);
```

I had assistance writing the above script and do not know what to change. Simply changing .live to .on  doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ --- there are examples in the documentation how to do that

Comment: Before you use `.live()`, `.delegate()`, `.on()` or anything similar, take an hour or so and read up on *"event delegation"*. It's basically how these work *(sometimes with `.on()`)*, it's a pretty simple concept, and one of those things that everyone should understand.

Comment: @user1689607 - Thanks for the advice, I will read up.

Comment: Do you know why you were using `live` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#email-button, #text-button', function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Should do the trick. See http://api.jquery.com/live/ and http://api.jquery.com/on/.

However, since you're using IDs, you probably don't even need `.live()` or delegating `.on()`. So the way I'd write that would be simply:

```
function doButtons(btnA, btnB, divA, divB) {
    btnA = $(btnA); btnB = $(btnB); divA = $(divA); divB = $(divB);

    // Make sure it is not already active, no use to show/hide when it is already set
    if (btnA.hasClass('dark_button_span'))
        return; 

    // See if div is visible, if so hide, then show first div.
    if (divB.is(":visible")) {        
        divB.fadeOut("slow", function  (){
            divA.fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }
    else // If already hidden, just show the first div.
        divA.fadeIn("slow");

    // Add and remove classes to the buttons to switch state.
    btnA.addClass('dark_button_span').removeClass('light_button_span');
    btnB.removeClass('dark_button_span').addClass('light_button_span');
}

$('#email-button').click(function () {
     doButtons(this, '#text-button', '#email-form', '#text-form');
});
$('#text-button').click(function () {
    doButtons(this, '#email-button', '#text-form', '#email-form');
});
```

Comment: Your re-write of the code works great and I think I will take the advice and not use `.live()` or `.on()`  Thanks!

Comment: @Lynda glad it worked! (Honestly I didn't actually test the rewrite. :P)

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for on is

```
$("containerElement").on("click", "targetElement(s)", function(){ });
```

So in your case it could be

```
$("body").on("click", "#email-button, #text-button", function(){ });
```

But being more specific than `body` is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.on` doesn't use event delegation unless you provide it a selector. In the above code, `.live` listens for events at the `document`, but that's far too much bubbling. If we were to implement it with `.on` though we would do the following:

```
var handler = function( e ) {
    console.log( "Clicked" );
};

$( document ).on( "click", "#email-button, #text-button", handler );
```

Again though, it isn't really all that wise to listen for events on the `document`; ideally you would pick an element just above your selector. So if `#email-button` and `#text-button` have a common parent, you should use that in place of `document`.